# Reading data from db

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have db and here JSON file from it:

```json
{
  "User": {
    "mail@gmail::com": {
      "-NKTbcSqxmB4XImNrpDq": {
        "Q": 0,
        "W": 0,
        "QW": 0,
        "WQ": 0,
        }
    },
mail@gmail:com": {
      "-NKTbcTUBxMsXYopKMO-": {
        "Q1": 0,
        "W1": 0,
        "QW1": 0,
        "WQ1": 0,
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I need to read data once time, when button is pressed, so i need use this listener:

```java
database.child("User").child(getMail1).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            User value = dataSnapshot.child("User").child(getEmail1).getValue(User.class);
            //saving data in sharedPreferences
            PreferenceConfig.Q1(getApplicationContext(), Q1);
            PreferenceConfig.W1(getApplicationContext(), W1);
            PreferenceConfig.QW1(getApplicationContext(), QW1);
            PreferenceConfig.WQ1(getApplicationContext(), WQ1);
        }
    });
```

getEmail - variable mail@gmail::com
USER_KEY - variable whith have id of user Immediately after this, I create for the second mail exactly the same code as above, only with other values:

```java
database.child(USER_KEY).child(getMail).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            User value = dataSnapshot.child("User").child(getEmail).getValue(User.class);
            //saving data in sharedPreferences            PreferenceConfig.Q(getApplicationContext(), Q);
            PreferenceConfig.W(getApplicationContext(), W);
            PreferenceConfig.QW(getApplicationContext(), QW);
            PreferenceConfig.WQ(getApplicationContext(), WQ);
        }
    });
```

getEmail - var whitch have data mail@gmail:com
and here is full code:

```java
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
database.child("User").child(getMail1).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            User value = dataSnapshot.child("User").child(getEmail1).getValue(User.class);
            PreferenceConfig.Q1(getApplicationContext(), Q1);
            PreferenceConfig.W1(getApplicationContext(), W1);
            PreferenceConfig.QW1(getApplicationContext(), QW1);
            PreferenceConfig.WQ1(getApplicationContext(), WQ1);
        }
    });
database.child("User").child(getMail1).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            User value = dataSnapshot.child("User").child(getEmail).getValue(User.class);
            PreferenceConfig.Q(getApplicationContext(), Q);
            PreferenceConfig.W(getApplicationContext(), W);
            PreferenceConfig.QW(getApplicationContext(), QW);
            PreferenceConfig.WQ(getApplicationContext(), WQ);
        }
    });
});
```

But the data does not come from the database. There is no error, although I display it like this:

Log.e("TaskEEEE", String.valueOf(task.getException()));
Why is the data not read??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you get the data at path `/User/$getMail1` from your database, the `task` variable contains a result snapshot of only that data. You can get this result by calling:

```
database.child("User").child(getMail1).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            User value = task.getResult().getValue(User.class); // 
            ...
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [getting data once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data_once), on which I based this answer.

---

In addition, it seems you have a push key under the email, which will require you to either know the key or use a loop over the child nodes to get to the properties:

```
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: task.getResult().getChildren()) { // 
            User value = userSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
        }
```

Comment: I have error: `Permission denied`
And: `E/FirebaseAnalyticsUtils: error:java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must not be called on the main application thread`

Comment: well, i fix them and i haven`t any errors but data didn`t saved. Is trouble with JSON file, whitch sends data in String type and i trying to get it like Integer?

Comment: You may have more problems, but does the explanation I gave in my answer make sense? Did you check the documentation I linked too, and does it make sense based on both of those why your original approach doesn't work and how what I showed in my answer improves on that (as it is what the documentation does)? It is important that you understand both, before we dig any further into more problems you may have. --- I added an update on another problem I spotted in your code.

Comment: I read all doc from official fb site. Im here cuz i have a lot of questions whith i didn`t understand

Comment: That's a good reason to be here, and we're here because we want to help. In order to do so efficiently, and build a meaningful knowledge base for others, it is important that you follow the site guidance like [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). While reading the users fro the database may be a single use-case for your app, there are many potential problems in there. The more you isolate the question on a single problem/API call, the more likely it is we can help.